# Add script path to xslt file

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

I have xslt template with javascript and xml file. xslt and js files are located in `folder1` and xml file in `folder2`.

```
folder1     | folder2
------------+--------
*.xslt,*.js |*.xml
```

But javascript code works if it's file is located in `folder2` too, also it works when the full path to `*.js` is in xslt template:  `<script src="C:\folder1\sorttable.js"></script>`. It is not very comfortable, because on the other computers path can be different. Can I define path to *.js another way?

Answer (score 0):

Use a relative path: `<script src='..\folder1\sortable.js' />`

The idea is to tell it to go up one from the current directory, into folder1 for sortable.js.